# Point transparency in draw command for a GAM

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been using `draw()` command, from `gratia` package in R, in order to visualize a multivariate GAM, including a smooth factor for geographical data.

The main problem is that the produced graph is slightly unreadable due to the opaqueness of the points. I am going to be using some made up code from [Gavin Simpson's gratia Guide](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/reference/draw.gam.html).

Here's the script used:

```
library(gratia)
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)

df2 <- data_sim(2, n = 1000, dist = "normal", scale = 1, seed = 2)
m2 <- gam(y ~ s(x, z, k = 40), data = df2, method = "REML")

draw(m2, contour = FALSE)
```

The [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEKM8.png) produced is not exactly what I am looking for, since I said again, my smooth factors demonstrates geographical data. Here, the points appear to have more space between them, and thus, they are more readable.

Using the `draw` command again on my GAM, the produced result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN5cT.png). The basic principles remain the same.

Comment: Hi, can you please add a reproducible extract of data so we can test your code? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you need tips and tricks about how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/articles/custom-plotting.html), it seems better to use `ggplot` to make the plot if you need further customizations.

See this paragraph about the `sm` object: https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/articles/custom-plotting.html#building-your-own-plot-by-hand

See the example below for a quick view. You can edit the `alpha` argument to make the points less "invasive". Of course you need to change the parameters of the fill scale to mimic the plot made with `gratia::draw()`.

```r
library(gratia)
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
library(magrittr)

df2 <- data_sim(2, n = 1000, dist = "normal", scale = 1, seed = 2)
m2 <- gam(y ~ s(x, z, k = 40), data = df2, method = "REML")
sm <- smooth_estimates(m2)
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = sm, aes(x = x, y = z, fill = est)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = z),
             data = df2, cex = 1.5, colour = "black", alpha = 0.05) +
  scale_fill_gradient2()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>